# FreeMarker Template: how to use combined conditions in <#if> </#if> block?

Tags: templates, if-statement, freemarker

I am wondering how to assess two conditions in an <#if> statement in FreeMarker Template ?
for example, in pseudo code:

```
if (i < 10 && i > 2)
    do something;
```

how to use two conditions in Freemarker? thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The tricky part in that expression is that the `>` operator ends the FTL tag. To work that around, you can write `<#if i < 10 && (i > 2)>` or `<#if i < 10 && 2 < i>` or `<#if i < 10 && i &gt; 2>`.

Comment: one doubt. similarly, isn't '<' used for starting ftl tags

Comment: @PSatishPatro Because we are already inside the tag, the parser only looks for a tag closing `>`, not for a tag opening `<`.

Comment: got it. Better to keep a bracket for the operation I feel

Comment: @PSatishPatro Or to use square bracket tag syntax, as `[` and `]` are not operators (I mean not in solo). Otherwise you can safely rely on `<` working without parentheses.